# vue 2 not picking up process.env variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables

I am rebuilding a project using Vue 2.5.2 and webpack 3.6.0
My .env file contains the following

```
VUE_APP_TEST=HelloWorld!
```

When I add the following mounted code to home page (defaulted from route '/')

```js
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    HomePageBlurb,
    EventList,
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['GetNextEvents']),
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['Events']),
  },
  async created() {
      if (this.Events.length === 0) {
      await this.GetNextEvents();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    alert('Process ENV: ', process.env.VUE_APP_TEST); // <-- THIS LINE!!!
  },
};
```

The VUE_APP_TEST is undefined.  The .env file is in the root of project (at the same level as the src folder).  My vue.config.js contains the following code: Which should be overriding the live API server with a local copy when running in dev.

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '^/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:7071',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          logLevel: "debug"
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

I have the HelloWorld in the env file just to prove it is being picked up (which it appears not to be) The real-world problem is that when I set VUE_APP_API_URL to be the live server

```
=https://myrealsite.azurewebsites.net/api/
```

and then in the vuex store do:

```js
async CheckParticipantByEmail({ commit }, payload) {
      const baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL;
      const urlEmail = `${baseUrl}getParticipantbyEmail`;
      . . .
}
```

the baseUrl is coming back as undefined.

As an experiment, in one of the store actions I have replaced the process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL with the actual live API path.  This is NOT being overridden by the dev proxy.  I don't know if the two issues are related.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong or need to add to the webpack build would be greatly appreciated.  (and YES, I have restarted the dev server using npm run dev)

Comment: Did you read the post all the way to the end? :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, you already did. My bad :-D

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) does not take a second parameter like console.log does, so at least your mounted code can be explained as simple syntax error.  I'm curious if you try somewhere `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` does it log a value? This is a env value injected by Vue (you don't need to add it to .env yourself)